# Linq query result changing not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var query = from table1 in dtSzotar
            where errorList.Any(word => table1.angol.Equals(word)) ||
                  errorList.Any(word=> table1.magyar.Equals(word))
            select new QueryObject
            {
                Lesson = table1.lesson,
                English = table1.angol,
                Hungarian = table1.magyar,
                Answer = "",
            };
foreach (QueryObject row in query)
{
      String tmp;
      ((App)Application.Current).Answer.TryGetValue(row.English, out tmp); 
      row.Answer = tmp;
}

dgInCorrect.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

I'm trying to display wrong user's answers in the datagrid too. `tmp` contains the answer, but it's not added to `row.Answer`.
Also There's an extra empty row at the end of the datagrid. What am i doing wrong?

Here's QueryObject.cs:

```
class QueryObject
{
    private int lesson;
    private String english;
    private String hungarian;
    private String answer;

    public int Lesson { get { return lesson; } set { lesson = value; } }
    public String Hungarian { get { return hungarian; } set { hungarian= value; } }
    public String English{ get { return english; } set { english= value; } }
    public String Answer{ get { return answer; } set { answer= value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over an `IEnumerable<QueryObject>`. Instead, turn your query into a list earlier, then it should work:

```
var query = (from table1 in dtSzotar
            where errorList.Any(word => table1.angol.Equals(word)) ||
                  errorList.Any(word=> table1.magyar.Equals(word))
            select new QueryObject
            {
                Lesson = table1.lesson,
                English = table1.angol,
                Hungarian = table1.magyar,
                Answer = "",
            }).ToList();

// now query is a List<QueryObject>
foreach (QueryObject row in query)
{
      String tmp;
      ((App)Application.Current).Answer.TryGetValue(row.English, out tmp); 
      row.Answer = tmp;
}

dgInCorrect.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much! Any thoughts about the last empty row?

Comment: empty row seems to be unrelated to this code portion, Thank you again